# Text to Voice in Urdu flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using flutter-tts in my application to convert urdu text to urdu speech but there the language is not supported by the package. Is there any way i can do this ?

```
void trans() async {
    await translator.translate(lang.text, to: 'ur') 
        .then((output) {
      setState(() {
        out = output
            .toString(); //placing the translated text to the String to be used
      });
    });
    print(out);
    flutterTts.setLanguage("ur-PK");
    await flutterTts.speak(out);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:tts/tts.dart';

void main() => runApp(TextToSpeech());

TextEditingController controller = new TextEditingController();

class TextToSpeech extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("Text to Speech"),
    ),
    body: Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
            child: TextFormField(
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              controller: controller,
            ),
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text("SPEAK"),
            onPressed: speak,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
}
}

speak() async {
Tts.speak(controller.text);
Tts.setLanguage('ur-PK');
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.